# Why can't I append something to a list?

Tags: python

I am currently having a bug with my code, and I need help fixing it.
Basically, when I try and append something to a list, it only works for certain arguments.

Here is a snipet(NOT the full code):

```
elif sentencearray[x] == " ":
   lengthlist.append(len(longestword))
   wordlist.append(str(*longestword))
   longestword.clear()
```

When I try and run my code, `wordlist.append(str(*longestword))` works, but `lengthlist.append(len(longestword))` doesn't. All the variables are defined. It's just that when I try and print `lengthlist`, it turns out empty, even though I JUST appended something in it. I'm pretty sure the lines are tabbed the same. Can somebody PLEASE explain why this is happening?

P.S if it's some stupid mistake, I'm fairly new at python, so I might make some of these mistakes here and there.

Here is the full code:

```
# Online Python - IDE, Editor, Compiler, Interpreter

sentence = input("enter sentence here: ")
sentencearray = list(sentence)
sentencelength = len(sentencearray)
x = 0
y = 0
counter = 0
numvowels = 0
numletters = 0
numuppercase = 0
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
uppercaseletters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z', 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
valuelist = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
knownletters = []
longestword = []
wordlist = []
lengthlist = []
knownletters.append(sentencearray[x])
for x in range(0,len(sentencearray)):
    for y in range(0,10):
        if sentencearray[x] == vowels[y]:  
            numvowels += 1
for x in range(0,len(sentencearray)):
    for y in range(0,26):
        if sentencearray[x] == uppercaseletters[y]:  
            numuppercase += 1
for x in range(0,len(sentencearray)):
    for y in range(0,52):
        if sentencearray[x]==letters[y]:
            longestword.append(sentencearray[x])
            for z in range(0,len(knownletters)):
                if sentencearray[x] != knownletters[z]:
                    counter += 1
            if counter == len(knownletters):
                    numletters += 1
                    knownletters.append(sentencearray[x])
            counter = 0
        elif sentencearray[x] == " ":
            lengthlist.append(len(longestword))
            wordlist.append(str(*longestword))
            longestword.clear()
for a in range(0,len(sentencearray)):
    for b in range(0,51):
        if sentencearray[a] == letters[b]:
            x += 1
            valuelist[b] = valuelist[b] + 1
print("# of vowels:" + str(numvowels))
print("# of uppercase letters: "+ str(numuppercase))
print("# of unique letters: " + str(numletters+1))
print("# of times the most frequent letter appears: "+ str(max(valuelist)))
print(longestword)
print(len(longestword))
print(lengthlist)
print(wordlist(max(lengthlist)))

print(knownletters)
print(x)
```

You can also check it out at:
https://www.online-python.com/5TYKzmJO9g

Comment: Don't post images of code, post a text copy of the code

Comment: Sorry, I just changed that.

Comment: That `append` happens within an `if` statement, so if it's not happening, it's because that condition never becomes true.  Also, you need to be introduced to the string split() method.  it will change your life, https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Comment: And can you help me on the problem?

Comment: Be aware that Python has some nice features for testing if one value is in a list of other values. For example: `if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']: # letter is a vowel`

Comment: hey JeffUK, the wordlist.append line is working in the if statement.

Comment: Also, note that `range(0,N)` is more commonly written, and identical to, `range(N)`.

Comment: In both Python 2 and 3, `wordlist.append(str(*longestword))` throws various errors depending on what exactly it encounters. You pass `str` *one* thing you want a string version of, not multiple. You could do `''.join(longestword)` instead, using the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to produce a string.

Comment: And once you fix that, `print(wordlist(max(lengthlist)))` also throws an error, because `wordlist` is a list; you're trying to call `wordlist()` like a function, which doesn't work.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to start getting a feel for how to track these things down. I've never used Online Python; maybe you have to enable error messages or something? Because again, in standard Python, your code above doesn't even finish running for me. (Note, that article talks about compiling code, which isn't relevant to Python, but a lot of it is good info.)

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't what you asked for exactly... but there are so many Python features you're missing out on I couldn't resist putting together a 'more pythonic' example.

It's not entirely complete (I don't have your spec)  and specifically it will treat numbers and special characters as 'letters',  there are a number of ways you could exclude them.

```
vowels = ['A','E','I','O','U']
    
raw_sentence = input("Enter Sentence Here")
    
char_usage = {}
uppercase_count = 0
vowel_count =0

for char in raw_sentence:

    #Take an uppercase copy of our character for later
    upper_char = char.upper()
    
    #instead of `valuelist`, we maintain a dictionary of character:occurance 
    if upper_char in char_usage:
        char_usage[upper_char]+=1
    else:
        char_usage[upper_char]=1

    #Instead of checking against a list, if a character == character.upper() it's upper case
    if upper_char==char:
        uppercase_count +=1

    #use 'in' to check if a character is a vowel
    if char.upper() in vowels:
        vowel_count +=1

print("Number of Vowels",vowel_count)
print("Number of Uppercase Letters",uppercase_count)

#the largest value in our char_usag dictionary answers this question:
print("# times most frequently used letter appears",max(char_usage.values())) 

#and the length of the dictionary answers the next:
print("Unique Letters", len(char_usage))

#use 'split' to split a string into words by white-space
sentence = raw_sentence.split() #convert string into a list of words

#Print the longest word:
print("Longest Word:", max(sentence, key=len))
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I was driven to do something similar. This does change some behavior (such as counting "words" even if they include numbers). I doubt that's a problem, or that the original code had such specifics in mind, but it would be good to mention as a caveat in your answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I never knew there was a "upper" function that turned the letter uppercase. But, can you explain to me how this solves the appending issue? Like, is there a reason why the first append function works but the second one doesn't?

Comment: @DChen if you want to understand it, you need to debug your code, step through the code and see why that line of code is never being executed.

Comment: @DChen As I mentioned in the comments to your question, you have two errors in the posted code. Not just mistakes—actual errors that, when I tested, caused the program to hit an exception before it could finish running. When I fixed those, the list appeared to print properly for me. I really wonder if a) the code you posted and the code you're running are different, or b) the Python interpreter you're running isn't printing error messages for some reason.